# WSDL file to Jar File

Tags: java, web, soap, wsdl

I have WSDL file URL and I want to create JAR file and need use in another project.

I have try to convert with below scenarios

1.Using wsimport command to Java files and using this java files create maven project as packaging JAR

> wsimport -keep -wsdllocation /MyService.wsdl

2.Using ANT build (create build.xml file create target for export JAR)

```
<target name="dist" depends="compile" description="generate the distribution">
        <buildnumber />
        <!-- Create the distribution directory -->
        <mkdir dir="${dist}/lib" />

MyApplication-${version}.${build.number}.jar -->
        <jar destfile="${dist}/lib/MyApplication-${version}.${build.number}.jar" basedir="${build}" />
    </target>
```

above both scenarios JAR exported but when I deployed in server getting below Exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

what I am doing wrong ?
is there any simple way to convert wsdl to Jar?

Answer (score 0):

This Issue occur run time class not found.

I have add new Assembly in Eclipse -> specific project -> Web Deployment Assembly

select specific JAR,WAR,RAR or ZIP file from path and set.

and test again after this solved this issue.